# Populate select input from PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I need to populate an input select with the values of a table in the moment that the page loads.
This page will work as a NEW record in database or as MODIFY existing record.
This is my table structure.

```
    CREATE TABLE `PERSONAS` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `NOMBRE` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
      `CUIL` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `LOCALIDAD_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PARTIDO_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PROVINCIA_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `DNI` (`DNI`),
      KEY `NOM_AP` (`NOMBRE`,`APELLIDO`),
      KEY `CUIL` (`CUIL`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci$$

    CREATE TABLE `LOCALIDADES` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `PARTIDO_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `NOMBRE` varchar(80) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

The page with the form is called legajos_abm.php so, when I want a new PERSONAS, I call the page as legajos_abm?id=null but when I need to modify PERSONAS I call it legajos_abm?id=3 with the PERSONAS.ID as parameter.

This is an example of my html form:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id=formulario>
            <form id=formularioLegajo>
                <fieldset>
                    Nombres: <input id=nombre type=text />
                    Localidad: <input id=localidad type=select />
                    <!-- The rest of the fields........ -->
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I need is to populate the select input for LOCALIDAD_ID with the results of table LOCALIDADES. When ?id=null fill it with the whole table results, when ?id=x then fill it with the field of the row x.

Hope my english haven't messed around with the question.

Comment: Why don't you populate the `<select>` with PHP *before* the page loads?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really know how to do this. That's why I asked. I'm new to PHP and I've learned how to get results from a CLICK but not from a page load or before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
    <td style="text-align:right"><label>Provincia: </label></td>
    <td><select id="cmbProvincia" name="cmbProvincia" style="width:240px">
    <option value="0">Elija la provincia...</option>;
    <?php
        require_once('dataaccess.php');
        $legajos = new legajos();
        $legajos->cmbProvincias();
    ?>
    </td>
```

dataaccess.php

```
    $con = $this->conectarDB();
    $query = 'CALL SPR_CMB_PARTIDOS('.$provincia_id.')';
    $result = $this->con->query($query);

    while($row=$this->con->fetch($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['PROVINCE_ID'].'">' .$row['PROVINCE_NAME_TX'].
        '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
    $this->con->close();
```